# How to set attributes of the *next* character that is typed in NSTextStorage

Tags: ios, swift

It's simple enough to change the text attributes in a given range of `NSTextStorage`.

```swift
storage.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30), at: range)
```

But how do I change the attributes at the current cursor position so that the *next* character has different attributes?

(Think someone clicking the "bold" button in a toolbar with no text selected. No text turns bold, but the next character is bold.)

Comment: 'range' says it all.

Comment: Just a suggestion: find the cursor position, and create a range starting from there with 0 length, and pass that range to `addAttribute`?

Comment: Thought of that too, but length 0 doesn't apply attributes. Looks like it's `typingAttributes` >.< Figured it would be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UITextView.typingAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes) to achieve this.

> This dictionary contains the attribute keys (and corresponding values) to apply to newly typed text. When the text view’s selection changes, the contents of the dictionary are cleared automatically.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // This is the key part
    textView.typingAttributes = myCurrentAttributes

    // Allow system to control typing
    return true
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but the cursor doesn't reflect the typing attributes until a new character is added. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of waiting to set the typing attributes until user actually types something, you could try setting the typing attributes immediately when you change them. I'm not sure if it would work the way you want, is worth a try.

Comment: No sorry that's what I meant. Like the code above `shouldChange` is called and sets the typing attributes to a bigger font. But it in the textView the cursor is still looks the size of the smaller font. When you add a character it then jumps and gets bigger as it inserts a character with the new font size.

Comment: @MGA did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm updating `typingAttributes` but the cursor size remains the same until a character is typed.